# Roll a die until two consecutive equal outcomes. What’s the probability that the sum of all outcomes is an odd number?

Tags: probability, dice

Keep rolling a die until two consecutive outcomes are equal. What’s the probability that the sum of all outcomes(including the last two) is an odd number?

This is not a homework. It’s a combination (just came to my mind) of two easy problems:

What’s the probability took N rolls to see two consecutive equal outcomes?

The probability that the sum of N rolls of a die is odd?(which means there are odd number of odd outcomes, then it’s not hard to find the result is 1/2.)

My initial thought about the solution of this new problem was combining the results of the two simple questions. But then I realize these two events are not independent, applying the stopping rule changes probability of the second event, which is no longer 1/2.

I am wondering if it can be solved by calculating the probability of the second event (sum is odd) if we treated N as a fix number and then times the probability that the game is stopped at N rolls, then the solution is a form of summing up all weighted probabilities as an infinite series?

Comment: What are your thoughts on this problem?

Comment: You've posed a problem that can be resolved by reasoned mathematical arguments, but we ask a little more than just a problem statement.  What is the *context* for this problem?  Was it an assignment from a textbook?  Did it come about in designing a board game?  Is it similar to a problem you already know how to solve?  The required context can be added in many different ways, and I'd be happy to post an Answer if you can fill that in for your Readers.

Comment: Well, the sum of last two rolls are even.  So if the third to last roll (if there *was* a third to last roll) is odd the result is odd.  If the third to last roll is even the result is even.  What  is the probability that the third to last roll (if there was one) was even.  What is the probability that there wasn't a third to last roll.  If there wasn't a third to last roll, is the sum even or odd. What are your thoughts at this point.

Comment: Please see [this article on MathSE protocol](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33190/how-to-avoid-downvotes-for-beginners-questions/33236#33236).
As onerous as the article may appear to you, it provides a defense mechanism against the MathSE forum being used as a *do my homework* forum.  In particular, please see the **Edit-Tools** section of the article, and the portion of the article that discusses *showing work*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After any roll, provided the process is not yet complete, define the state of the process as the pair $(r,s)$ where

- $r=0$ or $r=1$ according as the previous roll is even or odd.$\\[4pt]$

  $s=0$ or $s=1$ according as the sum of all previous rolls is even or odd.

From each state $(r,s)$, let $p(r,s)$ be the probability that, when the process completes, the sum of all rolls is odd.

Considering how the value of $p(r,s)$ is affected by the parity of the next roll, we get
$$
\left\{
\begin{align*}
\;p(0,0)&=\,{\small{\frac{1}{3}}}p(0,0)+{\small{\frac{1}{2}}}p(1,1)\\[4pt]
\;p(0,1)&=\,{\small{\frac{1}{6}}}+{\small{\frac{1}{3}}}p(0,1)+{\small{\frac{1}{2}}}p(1,0)\\[4pt]
\;p(1,0)&=\,{\small{\frac{1}{6}}}+{\small{\frac{1}{3}}}p(1,1)+{\small{\frac{1}{2}}}p(0,0)\\[4pt]
\;p(1,1)&=\,{\small{\frac{1}{3}}}p(1,0)+{\small{\frac{1}{2}}}p(0,1)\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
\right.
$$
which can be regarded as a system of $4$ linear equations in $4$ unknowns.

Solving the system yields
$$
p(0,0)=\frac{15}{41},
\;\;\;\;\;
p(0,1)=\frac{26}{41},
\;\;\;\;\;
p(1,0)=\frac{21}{41},
\;\;\;\;\;
p(1,1)=\frac{20}{41}
$$
hence, since the state after the first roll is either $(0,0)$ or $(1,1)$, according as the first roll is even or odd, it follows that the probability of an odd total sum when the process completes is
$$
{\small{\frac{1}{2}}}
p(0,0)
+
{\small{\frac{1}{2}}}
p(1,1)
=
\frac{1}{2}
{\,\cdot\,}
\frac{15}{41}
+
\frac{1}{2}
{\,\cdot\,}
\frac{20}{41}
=
\frac{35}{82}
$$